# R Segment a SpatialLinesDataFrame representing a route by a specified distance

Tags: r, spatial

I have a SpatialLinesDataFrame that is meant to represent survey tracks.  These tracks are not strait lines where the route goes from a>b by the shortest distance, but instead the route twists and turns over its path (although no overlaps).  My ultimate goal is to segment these curvy lines into specified distances, taking into account the twists and turns, to calculate presence/absence for each segment.  Both in R and Arcmap I have segmented these lines, but it doesn't take into account the twists and turns along the path.

I believe the problem is that I need to convert the polylines into some kind of route class object, then segment that.  Suggestions of how this can be done?  Thanks in advance, Robin

Comment: You probably need to upload a small example data set and a graphic/drawing illustrating what you have and what you want to achieve.

Comment: your right...I will retract, re-evaluate, and repost.  R